# Update error: Not authorized to perform action: Invalid key

Tags: rest, rally

I am trying to update the Notes section in the rally user story using the Java toolkit for REST apis by passing the story reference and i keep getting the not authorized error.

```
void update(String description) throws IOException, URISyntaxException{
    //Look for the story.
    JsonObject storyJsonObject = find(this.storyNumber);

    // Get reference to the user story.
    String storyRef = storyJsonObject.get("_ref").getAsString();

    // Update the notes in Json object.
    String notes = storyJsonObject.get("Notes").getAsString();
    notes = notes + " <br/> " + description;


    // Update the story description.
    JsonObject updateStory = new JsonObject();
    updateStory.addProperty("Notes", notes);

    UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest(storyRef, updateStory);
    UpdateResponse updateResponse = this.restApi.update(updateRequest);

    checkForErrors(updateResponse, "update");

}
```

I have confirmed that I am able to update successfully from the UI using the same credentials. What am I doing woring

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What server do you use in your code?

```
String host = "https://rally1.rallydev.com";
```

or

```
String host = "https://sandbox.rallydev.com";
```

I replicated that problem on sandbox using the toolkit, and submitted a bug. On rally1 it appears to work consistently.

Comment: Thanks Nick. Looks like the issue was fixed. I am now able to update using the above sandbox host. Just curious - what was the bug id?